# In what is the pip.io UI built?

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, user-interface

Can anyone tell me if the http://pip.io UI is built in AJAX or only JavaScript?

The reason I ask this is that I noticed the UI is scalable in the browser. So with different screen resolutions it displays the same.

Comment: A scalable layout has nothing to do with Ajax, which is a technology to fetch data from the server without reloading the page. They may be using Ajax, but probably not to scale their content

Comment: “…is built in AJAX or only JavaScript?” [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) is indeed just a technique of [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript).

Comment: Well, thanks for pointing out I'm wrong about Ajax. But can I get a right answer how the content is scalable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean scalable as in it works with multiple resolutions?  The UI is designed with CSS which allows it to do so.  The rest of the frontend is built with Mootools, which handles all the fancy animations and api calls.

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer. I meant indeed that it works with multiple resolutions. I've been looking at your css and saw that the minimal width is 1024 and the minimal height is 500. Is that a technical decision, or is that as small as you needed to go?

As for the animations, they are fancy indeed. I like what you are trying to achieve by the social OS and admire that you've build this with such a small team.

Thanks for answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

We set the minimal height and width to accomodate for the design.  It is a technical decision because at a smaller resolution, some areas won't be able to render properly.  Also since most monitors are at least 1024px wide it shouldn't be an issue with most users.